# Display @ at the beginning of a TextView

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I need to display a string in a `TextView` that begins with the @ sign for a Twitter handle. When I put the string in my strings.xml, it doesn't like the @ at the beginning of the string and gives the error:

```
error: Error: No resource type specified (at 'twitter_handle' with value '@twitter_handle').
```

The layout.xml that has the `TextView` in it that uses the string resource gives the error:

```
The following classes could not be found:
- TextView (Change to android.widget.TextView, Fix Build Path, Edit XML)
```

There is no error if the @ sign is not at the beginning of the text, but anywhere else in the string.

If I escape the @ sign with either `&#64` or `\u0040`, the error goes away in the strings.xml, but I still get the error in the layout.xml.

Is there any way to use a string that begins with the @ sign in a `TextView` in a layout.xml?

strings.xml:

```
...
<string name="twitter_handle">@twitter_handle</string>
...
```

layout.xml:

```
...
<TextView
    ...
    android:text="@string/twitter_handle"
    ... />
...
```

Undoubtedly the problem has to do with the fact that a leading @ implies a reference to a resource, but shouldn't escaped @ signs be taken into account and work correctly?

**Update:** This issue was found to be a bug in the ADT Eclipse plugin. Installing the latest version recently released fixes the issue and escaping the @ in the strings.xml no longer causes an error.

Comment: Perhaps post the relevant parts of the actual `strings.xml` and `layout.xml`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Escape it with a leading slash, like this: `<string name="test">\@twitter</string>`

Edit: I should have read. You can programmatically assign the `String` to the `TextView`, by getting a string from it and set it to the `TextView`

```
 String twitter = getString(R.id.twitter);
 textView.setText(twitter);
```

Edit 2: Try this instead of the @ sign: `&#64;`. It's the html code for the sign.

Comment: This doesn't work either. It's essentially the same as the other escape codes I tried. It fixes the error in the strings.xml, but not the layout.xml.

Comment: Is there no way to do it in the layout.xml then, only programmatically?

Comment: try a little trick and add a leading space `\s` and then the `\@`. I don't know if it work, but atleast it's a try.

Comment: I noted I already tried both &#64; and \u0040 and both have the same results as \@, fixes the error in strings.xml, but not the layout.xml.

Comment: A leading space does avoid the error, but not with \s, that's not a valid escape. &#160; works however, but this isn't really a solution as it bumps the string over by a space naturally, causing it not to align correctly in the layout. It would be complex to account for this space in alignment as the fields it aligns with don't even contain text of the same font size.

Comment: Post the layout file. I suspect we are searching in the wrong direction.

Comment: Although its not, the layout can be as simple as only the `TextView` and the problem is still there (I just verified). I added the relevant parts of strings.xml and layout.xml to the question.

Comment: Make sure you are saving your files after making changes ;-)

Comment: The issue turns out to be a bug in ADT, which has been fixed in the latest update. Once the latest version was installed, this now works.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. Create a string in string.xml and use it in your layout code.

```
<string name="example"><Data>@twitter</Data></string>
```

@twitter is the content of your string

Answer (score 0):

This code works fine for me, just tested. Note the backslash on just the strings.xml

strings.xml:

```
...
<string name="twitter_handle">\@twitter_handle</string>
...
```

layout.xml:

```
...
<TextView
    ...
    android:text="@string/twitter_handle"
    ... />
...
```

and shows as `@twitter_handle` in the textview

Comment: I had been trying exactly this, saved, closed/reopened, cleaned project, even closed and reopened Eclipse. But it didn't work. I just checked for updates in Eclipse and downloaded a new version of ADT. It seems to work now! This must have been a recent update as I last checked in the recent couple of weeks. Glad the issue has been addressed though.